# PHP Form input type=radio - setting "checked" based on a variable value

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, radio-button

I'm a newbie creating a WordPress plugin stuck with setting "checked" based on a variable value. I'm working on a custom form.
I am struggling with syntax I think...

This is the bit that fails:

```
<input type="radio" name="reporter_alliance" id="reporter_talk" value="[TALK]" ' . if($currenta === "[TALK]"): . ' checked = "checked" '. ;'>
```

Here's the full function so far and the rest of it seems to work:

```
<?php
function report_roe_form( $reporter_alliance, $reporter_username)  

 {
    $current_u = wp_get_current_user();
    $current_uid = get_current_user_id();
    $currenta = get_user_meta($current_uid, 'alliance', true)[0];

    if($currenta === "[TALK]") echo 'true'; #test of the function (this works)

    echo ' 
    <form action="' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '" method="post"> 
        <div> 
            <label >Reporter Alliance <strong>*</strong></label> 
            
            <label for="reporter_chat">[CHAT]</label>
            <input type="radio" name="reporter_alliance" id="reporter_chat" value="[CHAT]">

            <label for="reporter_talk">[TALK]</label> 
            <input type="radio" name="reporter_alliance" id="reporter_talk" value="[TALK]" ' . if($currenta === "[TALK]"): . ' checked = "checked" '. ;'> 
        </div>
       
        <div>
            <label for="reporter_username">Reporter Username <strong>*</strong></label> 
            <input type="text" name="reporter_username" value="' . $current_u->user_login . '">  
        </div> 

        <div> 
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </div>
    </form>
    ';

 }
?>
```

I've seen lots online showing I should put `<?php ?>` around `if($currenta === "[TALK]"): . ' checked = "checked" '. ;` but I've tried various combinations that all fail.

I've tried several different combinations of putting things in single and double quotes but I just cant seem to get it.
Please can someone point a newbie in the right direction?

Comment: The duplicate should answer your question. You should also look into https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php though - outputting (HTML) content that is for the most part _static_, using echo statements, is not the best way to go to begin with.

Comment: I've changed the line to: `<input type="radio" name="reporter_alliance" id="reporter_talk" value="[TALK]" ' <?php if($currenta == '[TALK]') echo 'checked'; ?>'> ` and it doesn't work

Comment: Without changing any of the rest of it? When you are "in" an `echo` statement, then you must also be inside a `<?php ... ?>` block already - and those can't be nested.

Comment: Yes I am already in a php block

Comment: So - get out of it then, that is one easy way to deal with this situation. (See first comment & link I posted.) Or use the ternary operator, as suggested in the response to the duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I'm struggling to wrap my head around this, being so new. Trying to follow the info in the link I tried `<input type="radio" name="reporter_alliance" id="reporter_talk" value="[TALK]" '<' . '?php if($currenta == "[TALK]") echo "checked"; ?' . '>'> ` but this fails

Comment: OK I finally worked it out with your help. Took me a while to see what you were saying. I took it out of echo and exited php. Sorry I was so slow on this. I am learning as I go along.